# Python to control macros in mutliple instances of Excel

Tags: python, excel, vba, ms-office

How Do control with python multiple instances of Excel. This is not read/write, but more running macros on different workbooks.

Ex: 
Excel.exe running Book1.xls. has mac1
Excel.exe running Book2.xls. has mac2.

I got one instance to work, this first instance, which use 2003. 
I could not figure out the other instance which is 2007.

If 2 can be done, can 3 or 4, Or is the a limit. 
I thought of memcache launching the different instances, but really not sure, if workable.

TIA

working on apply this: 
[Using Python to program MS Office macros?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2141967/using-python-to-program-ms-office-macros)

Comment: Ok,  tried to figure this out, need more help.

Created a timeprint macro in pyVBA.xls works on 1st instance,
CLosed, 
opened in second instance, did not run
see dialog box in 1st instance. 
here the code 

##pyhton 2.6 

from win32com.client import Dispatch #as comDispatch

def doit():
    xl = Dispatch('Excel.Application')
    #xl.Visible = 1
    #xl.Workbooks.Open("C:\pyVBA.xls", True, True)
  
    xl.Run("C:\pyVBA.xls!Macro1")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately you cannot control which instance you get back when grabbing things from the ROT (running object table.) Only the first instance of an application will register itself.

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/238975

However, each document is registered in the ROT so in your case you may be able to find the right instance by looking for documents.

-Oisin

Comment: Can you give me an example for the above example? thanks... for quick answer

Comment: here's some C# to iterate through the contents of the ROT: http://www.vbusers.com/codecsharp/codeget.asp?ThreadID=69&PostID=1 - fire up two instances of excel, each with a different XLS loaded. Look in the ROT for excel.document instances (should be two), not excel.application (there will be only one)

Comment: I use python (trying,more) and VBA (trying, less)