# Run python script from VBA

Tags: python, vba

I have tried several solutions to run python script out of VBA.

My current solution that still doesnt work

```
Dim wsh As Object
Set wsh = VBA.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Dim windowStyle As Integer: windowStyle = 1
Dim waitOnReturn As Boolean: waitOnReturn = True

wsh.Run "C:\Python33\python.exe C:\Users\***\Documents\Promo models\get_sku_data.py", windowStyle, waitOnReturn
```

Any ideas?

Comment: This seems to be a VBA question, not a Python question. The trouble is with starting the Python interpreter process, not with the script itself. Also, why would you do this? ;)

Comment: I was asked to directly present my model results on Excel sheet for business people

Comment: Great, there are various Python libraries for modifying Excel sheets. No need to run Python via VBA..

Comment: Yeah, of course, but the problem is that I have to make it as a Excel-button solution =)

Comment: "Run" paths with spaces should likely be quoted.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Run and execute a python script from VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30531662/run-and-execute-a-python-script-from-vba)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I ended up with creation of .exe files instead of trying to call scripts itself.

So, I applied cx_Freeze, created .exe files and then called them as

```
Script_path1 = "C:\Users\" + Environ("Username") & "\Documents\Promo_models\get_sku_data\gui_changed.exe"
wsh.Run Script_path1, windowStyle, waitOnReturn
```

Answer (score 0):

[xlwings](http://docs.xlwings.org/en/stable/quickstart.html#call-python-from-excel) claims to make python from excel very easy:

```
Sub RandomNumbers()
    RunPython ("import mymodule; mymodule.rand_numbers()")
End Sub
```

> To make this run, just import the VBA module xlwings.bas in the VBA editor (Open the VBA editor with Alt-F11, then go to File > Import File... and import the xlwings.bas file. ). It can be found in the directory of your xlwings installation.

Comment: I would like not to use VBA extensions cause I need to call python script on other computers which will require Excel changes many times. Any way to call python script with default libs?

Comment: So excel runs on computer A but you need to call a python script on Computer B? For excel without xlwings I'm out of my knowledge.

Comment: No, it will work on different but same computers. On computer A both script and Excel will work together, the same config on computer B and etc. I just dont want to install this lib everywhere if possible

Comment: Ah okay. Maybe wsad597 answer can help you then.

Answer (score 0):

Here are a couple options to try.

```
RetVal = Shell("<full path to python.exe> " & "<full path to your python script>")
```

Or if the python script is in the same folder as the workbook, then you can try :

```
RetVal = Shell("<full path to python.exe> " & "ActiveWorkBook.Path & \<python script name>")
```