# How to send input from excel to python?

Tags: python, excel, input, xlsxwriter

I created a worksheet in excel using the python library xlsxwriter. I wrote in cell B2 "Input column to pivot on", and then in cell C2 I provided a drop down option list.

[image]

I created the drop down list by calling data_validation() on the worksheet.

```
workbook = writer.book
worksheet3 =  workbook.add_worksheet('Sheet3') 
prompt = "Select category to calculate variance of: "

worksheet3.write('B2', prompt)
worksheet3.write('C2', 'Max TemperatureF')
worksheet3.data_validation('C2', {'validate': 'list',
    'source': ['Max TemperatureF', 'Mean TemperatureF', 'Min TemperatureF', 'Max Dew PointF']})
worksheet3.set_column(2, 1, 35) # C2
worksheet3.set_column(2, 2, 20) # C2
```

After that I call writer.save() to save the worksheet. Now I'm trying to figure out how to get the value of cell C2. I want to add a submit button to the excel sheet in cell D2 using python. Then when the button is clicked I will grab the value  of C2 using python and store the value.

Has anyone ever done anything similar to this or know how to?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Xlsx*Writer* is solely for *writing* excel files. It cannot read from them, much less respond to the click of a button inside a worksheet.

To *read* Excel files, you can use [xlrd](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/xlrd). To *interact* with Excel, take a look at [xlwings](http://xlwings.org/).

Comment: Once I call writer.save() with the file I created with xslxwriter, I can call openpyxl to read the data from it.

Comment: Yes, and you could use xlwings to make the button call Python code.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't get perfectly what you want but if it could help you coud use the exec function.

```
>>> string = "print 'hello'"
>>> exec string
hello
```

Comment: Basically I'm trying to grab the value of a cell in excel using python. I already have a small sample of code that grabs the value --< workbook = load_workbook(filename="Weather_Data1.xlsx")
, worksheet3 = workbook.get_sheet_by_name('Sheet3'),
print worksheet3['C2'].value >-- But I want to create a submit button in excel using python that only when clicked I execute the code above

Comment: ehm, isn't Visual Basic better to do this?

Comment: It probably is in this one instance but collectively the project I'm working on is much easier in python

Comment: Try this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3567365/calling-python-script-from-excel-vba