# How to save XLSM file with Macro, using openpyxl

Tags: python, openpyxl, xlsm

I have **.xlsm** file with a **Macro** function. I'm loading it using **openpyxl** and write some data to the file and finally want to save as a different **.xlsm** file.

To save the file as XLSM file I have used below code in my Python script.

```
wb.save('testsave.xlsm');
```

But I cannot open that file if I saved as above. But if I saved it as **.xlsx** then I can open the file without the Macro function that original file had.

I want to open a Excel sheet that has Macro function, edit the file and save it as new **.xlsm** file using **openpyxl**. How can I do that?

Answer (score 46):

For me this worked, together with version `openpyxl==2.3.0-b2`

```
wb = load_workbook(filename='original.xlsm', read_only=False, keep_vba=True)
..
wb.save('outfile.xlsm')
```

It is also mentioend in the documentation here: http://openpyxl.readthedocs.org/en/latest/usage.html?highlight=keep_vba#write-a-workbook-from-xltm-as-xlsm

Comment: Is it possible to call and run the macro from python thereafter?

Comment: If you have MS Office installed and running Windows then you can run it with the [OLE api](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2141981/4200284). 

Otherwise you have to re-engineer the macro code with openpyxl in Python.

Comment: This link does not go to anything related to `xlsm`! In fact, if you go to http://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/latest/usage.html?highlight=xlsm You'll see, nothing is higlighted, since there is no anything about xlsm.

Comment: I think they removed that section about `xlsm` now, but still mention that the file type is supported. Important seems to set the `keep_vba` flag explicitly as it defaults to false. http://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/latest/usage.html?highlight=keep_vba

Comment: This method does not always keep the ActiveX components like the buttons connected to the code. Might be the same as the openpyxl bug of buttons being converted to images.

Comment: worked for me, macros are there, but buttons did not stay.

Comment: The latest version did not work for me, but 2.3.0 worked.

Comment: Works for me with Version 3.1.2. And it's mentioned in the documentation: https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/3.1.2/tutorial.html?highlight=keep_vba

Answer (score 9):

I don't know if this is still relevant for the person that asked the question, but I am dealing with the same problem and found a possible solution.

1. open the original file (say: `1.xlsm`) and do magic with openpyxl;
2. save as `2.xlsx`;
3. both files are actually zipped files: extract them to a temporary directory;
4. copy files from the directory of the original file to the directory of the `xlsx` files: one of the files is the macro (`vbaProject.bin`) and 2 of the files are necessary because they describe the type of the file among other things;
5. put all of the files that belong to the `xlsx` directory back into a zip file and rename this from `zip` to `xlsm`. This file contains the original macro and has been edited with `openpyxl`;
6. (*Optional*) delete the two temporary directories and the `2.xlsx` file.

Example code:

```
import openpyxl
import zipfile
from shutil import copyfile
from shutil import rmtree
import os

PAD = os.getcwd()

wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('1.xlsm')

#####
# do magic with openpyxl here and save
ws = wb.worksheets[0]
ws.cell(row=2, column=3).value = 'Edited'   # example
#####

wb.save('2.xlsx')


with zipfile.ZipFile('1.xlsm', 'r') as z:
    z.extractall('./xlsm/')

with zipfile.ZipFile('2.xlsx', 'r') as z:
    z.extractall('./xlsx/')

copyfile('./xlsm/[Content_Types].xml','./xlsx/[Content_Types].xml')
copyfile('./xlsm/xl/_rels/workbook.xml.rels','./xlsx/xl/_rels/workbook.xml.rels')
copyfile('./xlsm/xl/vbaProject.bin','./xlsx/xl/vbaProject.bin')

z = zipfile.ZipFile('2.zip', 'w')

os.chdir('./xlsx')

for root, dirs, files in os.walk('./'):
        for file in files:
            z.write(os.path.join(root, file))
z.close()

#clean
os.chdir(PAD)
rmtree('./xlsm/')
rmtree('./xlsx/')
os.remove('./2.xlsx')
os.rename('2.zip', '2.xlsm')
```

Comment: This solution is closest that I found, but still, I am getting some errors on file, that excel tries to recover. During this recovery, it (sometimes, not always) mess up the macros!

Comment: @Joost Is there anyway to keep the button graphic that control the macros? This script definitely maintains the macros VBA code, but the buttons that were in my other sheets to run the the code are gone. 

Here are my files including the input file, the output file and the script https://drive.google.com/file/d/1LOhUqAdjUWQFxCnZMRrdK8Iz4gRMACkw/view?usp=sharing . Maybe if you have time you could take a look

Answer (score 7):

I had the same issue when editing xlsm files using openpyxl. I tried most of the solutions/workarounds available in stackoverflow and in other forums. But none of them worked. Then I found [xlwings](https://docs.xlwings.org/en/stable/quickstart.html), this python library handles xlsm document, it preserve all the macros.

```
import xlwings as xw
wb = xw.Book('macro_xl.xlsm')
sheet = wb.sheets['Sheet1']
sheet.range('A1').value = 'From Script'
wb.save('result_file_name.xlsm')
```

Comment: Error : TypeError: 'Book' object is not subscriptable

Comment: it worked for me. try [this](https://www.onooks.com/xlwings-parameter-error-when-opening-workbook-using-excel-365-macos/) if approach above was of no success

Comment: Of note, potentially a good solution but doesn't work on Linux as XLWings doesn't work there.

Comment: @T.Shaffner yes... it needs an installation of Excel (and there is none on Linux)

Comment: Thank you, thank you, thank you! Super useful for programs that do a lot of work in Excel.

Answer (score 2):

That's right, openpyxl cannot read and write VBA code.

According to [this thread](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/openpyxl-users/2PKhuWTm1ME):

> I think you should not give the xlsM extension, because the file will
>   contain no VBA code. openpyxl is used to build xlsX files only.

Give a try to [this fork](https://bitbucket.org/amorris/openpyxl/overview) instead: if you pass `keep_vba=True` parameter to `load_workbook` it should do the job.

Hope that helps.

Comment: It didn't work for me. Here is my code for that `wb = load_workbook('template.xlsm', keep_vba = True);`

Comment: If this fork doesn't work - then, there is no way to make it work using `openpyxl`.

Comment: Cant find that fork but there is https://bitbucket.org/amorris/editpyxl/src/master/

Answer (score 0):

if your initial excel was created with python you might need to add the workbook.xml as well and parse the sheet xlms:

```
for sheet in range(1,4):
    with open('sheetX.xml', 'r') as myfile: 'r') as myfile:
        my_str=myfile.read()

substr = "<dimension ref="
inserttxt = "<sheetPr codeName=\"Sheet"+str(sheet)+"\"/>"

idx = my_str.index(substr)
my_str = my_str[:idx] + inserttxt + my_str[idx:]

with open('sheetX.xml', "w") as text_file:
    text_file.write(my_str)
```

Answer (score 0):

it's better to use xlwings to work with xlsm documents. I have tested it.

import xlwings as xw

wb = xw.Book(DATA.xlsm)