# Python to excel, openpyxl and file format not valid

Tags: python, openpyxl

The following is a simple snippet to open a .xlsm file, write a few values to it with python, and save it.

```
import openpyxl
from openpyxl import load_workbook

def toExcel():
    wb = load_workbook(filename="C:\\Users\\Mark\\Documents\\Test.xlsm")
    ws = wb.worksheets[0]
    ws.cell(row=1, column=1).value = 'foo'
    ws['A2'] = 'bar'
    wb.save("C:\\Users\\Mark\\Documents\\Test1.xlsm")

toExcel()
```

While the file opens and saves, it mentions file format not valid / corrupt and cannot open. If the .xlsm is removed from the wb.save, it will save and open after selecting excel with Open With. Why is the file format not valid as is?

Comment: What happens if you try making is `.xlsx` https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/default/tutorial.html#saving-to-a-file read the last note here.

Comment: Yes just reading this. Cheers

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to save XLSM file with Macro, using openpyxl](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17675780/how-to-save-xlsm-file-with-macro-using-openpyxl)

Comment: I can corroborate that mucking about with file.extension can solve this. I load an `xlsx` with apparenetly some extras, it wouldn't open if sent in a response as "xlsx". It did open in libre office. When the file.extension was changed to `xlsm` the file could be opened.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From here: https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/default/tutorial.html#saving-to-a-file

> Note
>
> The following will fail:

```
>>> wb = load_workbook('document.xlsx')
>>> # Need to save with the extension *.xlsx
>>> wb.save('new_document.xlsm')
>>> # MS Excel can't open the document
>>>
>>> # or
>>>
>>> # Need specify attribute keep_vba=True
>>> wb = load_workbook('document.xlsm')
>>> wb.save('new_document.xlsm')
>>> # MS Excel can't open the document
>>>
>>> # or
>>>
>>> wb = load_workbook('document.xltm', keep_vba=True)
>>> # If us need template document, then we need specify extension as *.xltm.
>>> # If us need document, then we need specify attribute as_template=False.
>>> wb.save('new_document.xlsm', as_template=True)
>>> # MS Excel can't open the document
```

Comment: Yes I just read this, sadly. Are there additional libraries that will allow me to build in macros as well as python?

Comment: Sorry, no idea. I typically only use basic excel functionality in my tasks. good luck!

Comment: wb = load_workbook(filename='C:\\Users\\Mark\\Documents\\Test.xlsm', read_only=False, keep_vba=True)

This solved it, I can now save in xlsm after opening it like this

Comment: nice, you should write it up as an answer under "answer my own question"

Comment: even with `wb = load_workbook(filename='C:\\Users\\Mark\\Documents\\Test.xlsm', read_only=False, keep_vba=True) ` I cannot open excel and shows `corrupted`, im only writing in cells which have nothing to do with the macro buttons on the excel,anyone knows how to resolve?

Answer (score 6):

I found this post because I was trying to create a `.xlsm` file from scratch using openpyxl. I figured out that I was getting this error because when you load the workbook you need to have `keep_vba=True` as the second parameter passed to the `load_workbook` function.

So this is what your `load_workbook` function should look like:

```
wb = load_workbook(filename="C:\\Users\\Mark\\Documents\\Test.xlsm", keep_vba=True)
```

As a side note, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59585265/is-there-any-way-to-create-a-xlsm-file-from-scratch-in-python/59586796#59586796) is my post that talks about creating a `.xlsm` file from scratch using openpyxl.

Comment: That did it for me. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You need to save to `xlxm` format first and then convert to `xlxs`:

```
wb = openpyxl.Workbook()

xlxm_tmp_file_path = "tmp_file.xlsm"
xlxs_local_file = "file.xlsx"
wb.save(xlxm_tmp_file)

wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(xlxm_tmp_file, keep_vba=True)
wb.save(xlxs_local_file)
```