# is there any way to create a .xlsm file from scratch in python?

Tags: python-3.x, xlsm

I am using python 3.8.1 on a mac and am trying to create a `.xlsm` file from scratch. I have looked at openpyxl and xlsxwriter, both of them are able to create `.xlsx` files from scratch and both can edit existing `.xlsm` files but I can't find any thing about actually creating a `.xlsm` file from scratch.

I've looked over the openpyxl documentation [here](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) and the xlsxwriter documentation [here](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/) but I have not been able to find anything about how to create a `.xlsm` file from scratch. I can't even find anything about how to convert a `.xlsx` file to an `.xlsm` file.

The closest I have come is that you can use `vba_extract.py` which is included in xlsxwriter to extract a file named `vbaProject.bin` from an existing `.xlsm` file which you can then add to a `.xlsx` file and then you can save it as a `.xlsm` file, but I need to create a `.xlsm` file from scratch, not relying on having some file there to use to create it.

Is there anything out there with openpyxl, xlsxwriter or any other utility I can use with python 3.8.1 to create a `.xlsm` file from scratch without having to depend on having an existing `.xlsm` or a `vbaProject.bin` file? As always a correct, clearly explained answer will be marked as accepted and will be upvoted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to both Alexander Pushkarev and APhillips for helping out with this question. Going off of Alexander's post I was able to figure out a hack to get this to work. I'm not really proud of this, but it works.

Running Alexander's code I get this error:

> Exception ignored in: 
>   Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/zipfile.py",
>   line 1819, in **del**
>       self.close()   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/zipfile.py",
>   line 1836, in close
>       self.fp.seek(self.start_dir) ValueError: I/O operation on closed file.

I played around with this and found out that if I took out `keep_vba=True` from the `load_workbook` function the code ran but I still got the error I noted above when trying to open the `.xlsm` file with Excel.

So, looking at the latest error I saw the last line says

> I/O operation on closed file.

I looked at openpxyl documentation and tried opening the file without the `keep_vba=True` option before opening it with `keep_vba=True` and it worked.

So excuse this ugly code, but this will work to create a `.xlsm` file from scratch without depending on any existing files (copy and paste ready):

```
from openpyxl import Workbook
from openpyxl import load_workbook

wb = Workbook()
ws = wb.active
ws['A1'] = 42
ws.append([1, 2, 3])
wb.save('new_document.xlsm')
wb1 = load_workbook('new_document.xlsm')
wb2 = load_workbook('new_document.xlsm', keep_vba=True)
wb2.save('new_document.xlsm')
```

Comment: weird development, I don't know if it was due to a python version upgrade or something else, but now I am able to run the code above without the line that reads `wb1 = load_workbook('new_document.xlsm')` and it works just fine.

Comment: Hi, following works for me on OpenPyXL version 3.0.3 :`from openpyxl import Workbook, load_workbook

filename = "New_macro_workbook.xlsm"

wb = Workbook()
wb.save(filename)
wb2 = load_workbook(filename, keep_vba=True)
wb2.save(filename)`

Comment: What if I have to insert values into existing `.xlsm` excel, though I keep `keep_vba=True` I get the error that file is corrupted

Comment: BIG THANK YOU FOR THIS PIECE OF CODE! Solved one of my problems that I have been struggling for the last several days!

Answer (score 1):

It appears as though an XLSM file is a zipped Excel file, containing macros, etc.

I was able to find a potential fix [here](https://bitbucket.org/openpyxl/openpyxl/issues/294/reading-and-writing-an-xlsm-file-results) using `openpxyl`:

```py
import openpyxl as px
from openpyxl import load_workbook
import os
...
wbname='orig_fname.xlsm'
wb = load_workbook(filename=wbname, keep_vba=True)
...
wb.save('temp.xlsm')
os.rename('temp.xlsm', wbname)
```

Please let me know if it works for you.

Comment: running the code above I get this error: No such file or Directory: 'orig_fname.xlsm'

Comment: thank you very much for your input. I didn't upvote your answer because it did not work for me, but I did post the answer I came up with. Thank you though!

Answer (score 0):

To the best of my knowledge, `xlsm` format is essentially the same as `xlsx`, with the only difference that it can contain macroses (see https://wiki.fileformat.com/spreadsheet/xlsm/ for instance).

So, you can use openpyxl (https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/), and you don't need to do anything else other than saving your `xlsx` file with the `xlsm` extension (code is taken from the official doc and changed slightly):

```py
from openpyxl import Workbook
wb = Workbook()
ws = wb.active
ws['A1'] = 42
ws.append([1, 2, 3])
wb.save('new_document.xlsm')
```

However, there's a strange behaviour in openpyxl which is not documented properly, so to make file actually openable in the Excel you will also need:

```py
wb = load_workbook('new_document.xltm', keep_vba=True)
wb.save('new_document.xlsm')
```

There's a little bit of explanation for this here: https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/tutorial.html#saving-as-a-stream

So the complete code:

```py
from openpyxl import Workbook
wb = Workbook()
ws = wb.active
ws['A1'] = 42
ws.append([1, 2, 3])
wb.save('new_document.xlsm')
# and the workaround
wb = load_workbook('new_document.xltm', keep_vba=True)
wb.save('new_document.xlsm')
```

Comment: that's correct, i can save a file with the `.xlsm` extension and it get's created just fine, but I get an error when I try to open that file that says something along the lines of the file extension isn't correct or the file is corrupted. I know that the `.xlsm` extension is valid because if i create a `.xlsm` file using excel on my mac, i am able to open it just fine. Thanks for the suggestion though.

Comment: Strange, I was able to open the document (I used LibreOffice, though)

Comment: yeah, copied and pasted the code above, and the `.xlsm` file was created. again, however, when i tried to open the file, I get an error that says "Excel cannot open the file 'new_document.xlsm' because the file format or the file extension is not valid. Verify that the file has not been corrupted and that the file extension matches the format of the file."

Comment: @GharbadTheWeak I guess I found the problem - please see updated answer

Comment: i think this is close, but when i try to run the complete code example from above i get an this error: Exception ignored in: <function ZipFile.__del__ at 0x7ff6d00f2160>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/zipfile.py", line 1819, in __del__
    self.close()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/zipfile.py", line 1836, in close
    self.fp.seek(self.start_dir)
ValueError: I/O operation on closed file.

Comment: this is coming from the keep_vba=True part of the load_workbook statement. if i take out the keep_vba=True the code runs but i get the same error as before when trying to open the file

Comment: Thank you so much for your input on my question. Your code didn't work 100% for me but it definitely put me on the right track, I posted the answer I came up with based on your code. I didn't upvote your answer because it didn't work for me and I don't want to confuse anyone who looks at this but I thank you very much for your help!

Comment: @GharbadTheWeak Well done on finding the solution for the issue! You should mark your reply as accepted since it works