# How to create a XLSM file in Python

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl, xlsm

is there a way to create a new .XLSM file in python?
(alternatively)
Is there a way to create .XLSM file from a .XLS or .XLSX file within python?

```
from openpyxl import Workbook
wb = Workbook()
wb.save('myExcelFile.xlsm')
```

I tried the above but it creates a non-functioning/ corrupt file.
Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Just create an XLSM template and use that.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know anything about python or the openpyxl library but this snip might help, see the python comment.  I found it in the openpyxl docs https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/tutorial.html#data-storage

It says must keep specify the attribute keep vba=true

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Interestingly enough I had this exact same question earlier today. I figured out an answer (not pretty at all) but it works. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59585265/is-there-any-way-to-create-a-xlsm-file-from-scratch-in-python) is my post that details the answer and here is the code I came up with:

```
from openpyxl import Workbook
from openpyxl import load_workbook

wb = Workbook()
ws = wb.active
ws['A1'] = 42
ws.append([1, 2, 3])
wb.save('new_document.xlsm')
wb1 = load_workbook('new_document.xlsm')
wb2 = load_workbook('new_document.xlsm', keep_vba=True)
wb2.save('new_document.xlsm')
```

Answer (score 0):

@Gharbad The Weak @Salvatore Allegra Thanks for the answers, appreciated :)

[I found what I needed here](https://redoakstrategic.com/pythonexcelmacro/)

Tailoring it to what I needed:

```
import pandas as pd
filename = 'Name_here' + '.xlsx'
writer = pd.ExcelWriter(filename, engine='xlsxwriter')

filename_macro = 'Name_here' + '.xlsm' 
workbook = writer.book
workbook.filename = filename_macro
workbook.add_vba_project('vbaProject.bin')
writer.save()
```

**(1)** This creates a new *.xlsm* file

**(2)** It allows the attachment of a binary file containing a macro