# Exporting chart from existing xlsm

Tags: python-3.x, python-2.7, python-requests, wxpython

I have multiple xlsm files that contains charts. I want to export the charts in png format using python. Found multiple posts to export charts in xlsx but not xlsm. Could someone help me?

Comment: [Answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59586331/how-to-create-a-xlsm-file-in-python)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.