# Non-ASCII character '\xb7' of xlsm file

Tags: python, unicode, python-unicode

I am trying to run [vba_extract.py](https://github.com/jmcnamara/XlsxWriter/blob/master/examples/vba_extract.py) in Visual Studio by IronPython. The compilation returns an error:

[image]

```
An unhandled exception of type 'Microsoft.Scripting.SyntaxErrorException' occurred in IronPython.dll

Additional information: Non-ASCII character '\xb7' in file ../../python/vba_extract.py ../../../tests/test.xlsm on line 1, but no encoding declared; see http://www.python.org/peps/pep-0263.html for details
```

I searched this issue, and added encoding in Line 2 of `vba_extract.py`:

```
#!python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
```

But it still does not work.

Additionally, I tried the following two lines, which returned the same error:

```
engine.ExecuteFile(@"../../python/irrelevant.py ../../../tests/test.xlsm");
engine.ExecuteFile(@"../../tests/test.xlsm");
```

So I guess the problem is from the encoding of `test.xlsm`.

Could anyone help?

Comment: try `# -*- coding: latin-1 -*-`

Comment: still does not work... same error...

Comment: Is it complaining about test.xlsm? Plenty of non-ascii characters there, I'm sure.

Comment: It is possible, it is just an Excel file (with macros), so is there anything I could do?

Comment: that could help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17675780/how-to-save-xlsm-file-with-macro-using-openpyxl

Comment: Are you sure that's your exact first line of your file? The error is complaining about line 1.  The byte `0xb7` doesn't appear to be there. Maybe try deleting both lines entirely and retyping them in manually.

Comment: Please see my updates...