# Limit the number of worksheets in a excel file using python

Tags: python, excel

I need to limit the number of worksheets in a excel file to a specific number using python. The user cannot add a new worksheet once the number of sheets in that workbook reaches a particular number.

I couldn't find any solution using [xlsxwriter](https://github.com/jmcnamara/XlsxWriter), [openpyxl](https://bitbucket.org/openpyxl/openpyxl/src) or [xlrd](https://github.com/python-excel/xlrd)

Is there any option available using some other packages?

Comment: Does excel support this feature?

Comment: I dont know whether it has any such feature, since rows and columns can be restricted, i think there will be an option for this also.. I'm not sure about that

Comment: First - check if excel support it (which I'm really not sure). If it does - next thing is to see if any of the libraries implemented it. If not - it's time to implement and give it back to the open source community :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Excel doesn't have such functionality built in. [You can only disallow creating new sheets by protecting the workbook or with a VBA handler that reverses the operation immediately](https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/1772-excel-prevent-insert-worksheet.html).

Protecting the workbook [also disables other worksheet operations](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Protection-and-security-in-Excel-be0b34db-8cb6-44dd-a673-0b3e3475ac2d) like moving, renaming and hiding/unhiding which may or may not be desirable.

OTOH, the VBA handler can be more intelligent than the one on the link:

```vb
Private Sub Workbook_NewSheet(ByVal Sh As Object)
    If ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.Count > <Maximum> Then
        With Application
            .ScreenUpdating = False
            .DisplayAlerts = False
            Sh.Delete
            .DisplayAlerts = True
            .ScreenUpdating = True
        End With
    End If
End Sub
```

Of course, this will have no effect if one edits the file with a 3rd-party package that doesn't run VBA, or disables macros in Excel.

To have macros, the workbook must be saved as `.xlsm`, or Excel would give an error upon opening.

See [Working with VBA Macros — XlsxWriter Documentation](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/working_with_macros.html) about Python implementation. [`openpyxl` cannot work with macros, only preserve them at most](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17675780/how-to-save-xlsm-file-with-macro-using-openpyxl), and [`xlrd` looks like being designed to only read rather than edit](http://xlrd.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html). Alternatively, there's always Excel's own COM interface that `pywin32` can use.