# Python openpyxl saving xlsm file gets error when opening

Tags: python, xml, excel, vba, openpyxl

I have a script that opens an xlsm file and an xlsx file. It modifies the xlsm with data from the xlsx, then saves the xlsm file.  When i open that xlsm file after the script is run, I get an error shown in the image.[image]

The file then works fine but I get an XML error shown below:
[image]

The code I am using is:

```
import openpyxl
destwb = openpyxl.load_workbook(filename="C:\\627 Data\\winphy\\071-000-022-00 627 data.xlsm", read_only=False, keep_vba=True)

.....Code.....

destwb.save(filename="C:\\627 Data\\winphy\\071-000-022-00 627 data2.xlsm")
```

Comment: the repaired summary section is not closed, "summary" is missing

Comment: The Excel file errors are unfortunately not very helpful and without the file we can't help you.

Comment: I am not sure how I can attach the file to the thread but once i open the file and save it again, The errors are gone.

Comment: @mickNeill It seems that you saved it as a xls. I am not sure if `save` from the `openpyxl` can save xlsm file this way!

Answer (score 2):

I ran into something similar and pieced largely recycled code from this solution by [Joost](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7119722/joost) in this question: [How to save XLSM file with Macro, using openpyxl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17675780/how-to-save-xlsm-file-with-macro-using-openpyxl)

Apparently, openpyxl doesn't read or preserve all of the magic macro parts of an xslm when opening and saving. Since the files are in a zip format, the solution:

- Saves your work as an xlsx
- Opens the original xlsm as a zip and extracts the key parts
- Creates a new zip with the data from your saved xlsx and the above key parts
- Renames that as a xlsm

I took the sample code, turned it into a usable replacement for workbook.save(), fixed a missing file (likely Excel change since the original solution), added zip compression and creation of a backup file to the mix. May this do what you need.

```
def saveXlsm(wb, xlsmname):
'''Some crazy workaround to fix what openpyxl cannot when recreating an xlsm file. 
   Use as replacement for workbook.save()
'''
import zipfile
from shutil import copyfile
from shutil import rmtree

# Unzip original and tmp into separate dirs
PAD = os.getcwd()
wb.save('tmp.xlsx')
with zipfile.ZipFile(xlsmname, 'r') as z:
    z.extractall('./xlsm/')
with zipfile.ZipFile('tmp.xlsx', 'r') as z:
    z.extractall('./xlsx/')
# copy pertinent left out macro parts into tmp
copyfile('./xlsm/[Content_Types].xml','./xlsx/[Content_Types].xml')
copyfile('./xlsm/xl/_rels/workbook.xml.rels','./xlsx/xl/_rels/workbook.xml.rels')
copyfile('./xlsm/xl/vbaProject.bin','./xlsx/xl/vbaProject.bin')
copyfile('./xlsm/xl/sharedStrings.xml','./xlsx/xl/sharedStrings.xml')
# create a new tmp zip to rebuild the xlsm
z = zipfile.ZipFile('tmp.zip', 'w', zipfile.ZIP_DEFLATED)
# put all the parts back into the new Frankenstein
os.chdir('./xlsx')
for root, dirs, files in os.walk('./'):
        for file in files:
            z.write(os.path.join(root, file))
z.close()
os.chdir(PAD)
# humanize Frankenstein
bakname = xlsmname + '.bak'
if os.access(bakname, os.W_OK):
    os.remove(bakname)
os.rename(xlsmname, bakname)
os.rename('tmp.zip', xlsmname)
#clean
rmtree('./xlsm/')
rmtree('./xlsx/')
os.remove('./tmp.xlsx')
```