# how to update existing xlsm sheet with macros using pandas, openpyxl, xlwings without losing macros

Tags: python, pandas, csv, xlsm

First of all, I'll discuss my need from this post.....
Now I need to update existing excel `xlsm` file from another excel `csv` file, as this `csv` file is an exported `csv` from outlook mail inbox and this is the template of my outlook mail `csv`

```
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|------------|
|      Subject        |       Body       |    From: (Name)  | To: (Name) |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|------------|
|blabla LCAIN5678 bla |bla bla bla bla   |bla bla bla bla   |bla bla bla |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|------------|
```

As I working and analyze on this `csv` file, by using `str.extract` after I read with pandas and this is my extracting code as to extract specific data from the `csv` file, as to extract specific string like this `LCAIN5678` contains five characters and five numbers and then use `dropna()` with,

This code

```
# this object extract 5 chars and 5 numbers from specific column in csv
replaced_sbj_value = myOutlook_inBox['Subject']
.str.extract(pat='(L(?:DEL|CAI|SIN).\d{5})').dropna()
```

This is my `xlsm` file read by pandas

```
gov_tracker_sheet = pd.read_excel(r'' + mydi
                              sheet_name
                              header=1)
```

and this is my `csv` file read by pandas

```
myOutlook_inBox = pd.read_csv(r'' + mydir + 'test.CSV
                          encoding='latin-1')
```

Then I inisialize it like this

```
myOutlook_inBox["Subject"] = replaced_sbj_value
print (replaced_sbj_value)
```

To be like this way

```
|-----------------|
|    Subject      |
|-----------------|
|   LCAIN5678     |
|-----------------|
```

Then I create a condition using some functions like `loc` `str.contains`

Like this condition as this conditions is filters for some texts in the `csv`

```
# Condition 1: any mail from mowafy to te
frm_mwfy_to_te = myOutlook_inBox.loc[myOutlook_inBox['From: 
(Name)'].str.contains("mowafy", na=False) \
                                 & myOutlook_inBox['To: 
(Name)'].str.contains("te", na=False)] \
.drop_duplicates(keep=False)
```

Then I create a variable by using `join` method to `join` variable `frm_mwfy_to_te` to the excel `xlsm` file I want to update

```
filtered_data_cond1 = gov_tracker_sheet.loc[
gov_tracker_sheet['SiteCode']
.str.contains('|'.join(frm_mwfy_to_te.Subject))]
print(filtered_data_cond1)
```

as the out of this just get me the rows I want to update from the `xlsm` excel file

So finally here a create a tuple value as to update the `Dataframe` by using this variable
And this is my `tuple` variable

```
values = tuple(filtered_data_cond1['Pending  '].values.tolist())
```

As this is the output of my `tuple` value

```
(u'TE', u'PP', u'TE', u'TE', u'TE', u'TE', u'TE', u'TE', u'TE')
```

So from here I started using `Regex` by using `replace` method.

And this is my replace variable I created

```
updated_gov_tracker = gov_tracker_sheet.replace(to_replace=values,
                                            value='xxxxxxxxxxxx', 
regex=False)
```

This code works but It just replaces all rows in the `xlsm` file which contains `TE` I need to update the needed rows only

and I used another way some think like this but it's doesn't work fine

```
updated_gov_tracker=re.sub(values,"xxxxxxxxx",gov_tracker_sheet)
```

Second Thing I need I want to replace my new `Dataframe` with the old `xlsm` table sheet without losing my `macros` in the excel

## Edited

## and this is my existing excel file I want to update looks like

[image]

## and this is my `csv` Outlook inbox excel looks like this

[image]

## Now after searching I've found `xlwings` also could help me, by selecting the range of the row and write the new `updatedvalue`, So I need now to take the `tuple` variable, as this variable contains a `strings` of column called site code, finally I need now to update the excel xlsm first sheet depending on values rows in this tuple

## Example

I have a tuple value something like this
    LCAIN12345
    LCAIN54632
    LCAIN78965
    blablabla

Now this values already existing in the `xlsm` sheet in column called `SiteCode` in sheet called `Gov_Tracker` I want to update some columns depending `rows` on this values, like I want to update in columns called `Pending`, `Pending Status` and blablabla

Now I want to modify this columns rows values like change the old value in `Pending`, `Pending Status`, blablabla `equals` to the new values `TE`, Waiting TE Acceptance` blablabla

I hope this info is clear enough

Comment: gov_tracker_sheet.. ?

Comment: @iamklaus actually `gov_tracker_sheet` is just my master sheet in the `xlsm` just please check my post edits

Comment: You should split this problem into two different questions. Your first problem, is still unclear to me: How does your current data look and how do you want it to look?
Your second problem is different, you want to create (or update, but I suggest create) a xlsm with the xslxwriter.

Comment: Your question isn't clear: "but It just replaces all rows in the xlsm file which contains TE I need to update the needed rows only" - what are the needed rows? Can you post several rows, and explain which are not "needed" and should be left as-as is, and which are "needed" and what they should look like after `replace`?

Comment: @Jack Fleeting @Frieder actually the needed rows is in the `tuple` value I put my need `rows` in the `tuple` value and my second question is just I want to replace the old master which is the `gov_tracker_sheet `  new sheet in the `xlsm` file with the new updated `Dataframe` but without losing macros in the xlsm file because I run macro after updating the `xlsm` file

Comment: could you please some data for gov_tracker_sheet ?

Comment: @iamklaus check my edit please

Comment: PD can only *read* Excel, but not write it. XlsxWriter can only *write* xlsx, but not *update* files. So if you want to edit your file, you need to switch to another library that supports updating existing xlsm files.

Answer (score 0):

Easiest solution for creating a xlsm with XlsxWriter is to manually change the file ending, and then include the macros in an extra step (see [here](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/working_with_macros.html)):

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'First' : [5, 2, 0, 10, 4], 
                   'Second' : [9, 8, 21, 3, 8]})

writer = pd.ExcelWriter('test.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter')

df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet1')

workbook  = writer.book
workbook.filename = 'test.xlsm'
workbook.add_vba_project('./vbaProject.bin')

writer.save()
```

See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28169731/write-pandas-dataframe-to-xlsm-file-excel-with-macros-enabled). You can extract the macros (vbaProject.bin) with the vba_extract.py utility which is shipped by the XslxWriter package.

```
$ vba_extract.py macro_file.xlsm
Extracted: vbaProject.bin
```

Comment: your code means that I should create a new `excel` from scratch I need just modify please check my edit I posted some picture

Comment: This is not possible with xlsxwriter. See https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/introduction.html `It cannot read or modify existing Excel XLSX files.` You could try https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/index.html#module-openpyxl, but I have no expierence with it and I don't know if they support macros.

Comment: So I actually here I use `replace` function as to replace the needed values want to change in the `dataframe` so now the dataframe could be updated.... as I have more than 45 columns and more than 1000 rows so it's would be take a lot of time as to create these rows manually..... you got what I mean?

Comment: please could you check my edit I just posted pictures of templates excel files I am using to be clear enough, I really appreciate for your help....Thanks a lot

Comment: Your dataframe is a pandas object, but has nothing to do with your original excel file. The dataframe just holds all the data which is in the excel file, but changing data in the dataframe object does _not_ change your excel file.

Comment: Yeah I got you now, so finally of the result I should put my all data rows and columns manually in the python code then I use writer to update right?

Comment: No! I just said, if you want to _modify_ an existing excel file, you can _NOT_ use xlxwriter, because this library can only create new files. I don't know which library supports this, but you can try openpyxl.

Comment: so there's any materials here you could give me how can I use `openpyxl` to solve my case? I just want to modify only not to create a new excel

Comment: Yes there is, [original documentation](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/tutorial.html) and [some question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17675780/how-to-save-xlsm-file-with-macro-using-openpyxl) on SO on modifying a xlsm file.

Comment: really thanks a lot you helped me a lot...... any way I tried these sequence I posted with sql database it works fine but that's will take a lot  of time by using `database` `sqlAlchemy`