# Python pandas: how to speed up exporting dataframes to csv?

Tags: python, csv, pandas, export-to-csv

I am running some numerical simulations with python, pandas and scipy.
I run a set of scenarios, and for each scenario I create a detailed dataframe with lots of outputs, which I save to separate CSV files. Each CSV file is about 900 KB.

The line I use is, banally:

```
mydataframe.to_csv('myoutput.csv')
```

My question is: is there a way to speed the exporting process? Some specific parameters, a different library, etc. I ask because writing to CSV takes almost half the time of the total simulation: running 18 scenarios takes 17 seconds, 7.2 of which spent in the to_csv method.

PS I had initially wanted to write to Excel, but that's too slow, as per my other question: [Python: fastest way to write pandas DataFrame to Excel on multiple sheets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25863381/python-fastest-way-to-write-pandas-dataframe-to-excel-on-multiple-sheets)

Comment: Have you profiled this? can you compare the performance using [`np.savetxt`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.savetxt.html)

Comment: each dataframe has from 300 to 400 columns. How can I get np.savetxt to write column headings? I understand it has a header argument, but it doesn't seem to accept a list of column names.

Comment: As you can read in the docs (http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.savetxt.html), it is a string that will be written at the beginning of the file. So you can do `','.join(mydataframe.columns)`

Comment: I can't get np.savetxt to work with non-numerical arrays, which is a problem because my dataframe has many text fields.

Answer (score 0):

Try compressing the file:

`mydataframe.to_csv('myoutput.gz', compression='gzip')`