# How to quickly create excel sheet of high number of rows of data?

Tags: php, python, mysql, export-to-excel

I am using `XlxsWriter` module of python to create worksheet. I have around million rows of data to export from my query result. I have optimized the query but it is taking around 230+ seconds to write into the worksheet.
I am using *for* loop to loop around the rows and writing them.

Is there alternative to export million rows of query results to `.xlsx` format?

Should I use *OUTFILE* from MySql instead to export into CSV format?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Referring to this benchmark https://stackoverflow.com/a/25869984/7923400 pyexcelerate is about twice as fast as XlxsWriter. There are some other options suggested there too.