# Fastest way to write dataframes list to Excel sheets with python

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dataframe

I have 50 **CSV** files of 20,000 rows each, I allready joined them and then split them by date. My result is a **list** of dataframes that I want to write each dataframe of the list to one sheet in an output excel.
I already try with:

```
with pd.ExcelWriter('output.xlsx') as writer:
        cont=0
        for x in List:
            x.to_excel(writer,sheet_name="csv_"+str(cont),index=False, engine='xlsxwriter',na_rep="NAN",startrow=1,startcol=1)
            cont+=1
```

But I get a memory error and it takes forever. So my question is, does anyone know how to write big dataframes to an excel sheet in a really fast way using python? Or I should use another language to write it?

I already have posted another question showing my error:
[Writing pandas dataframes to excel crash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62239696/writing-pandas-dataframes-to-excel-crash)

Comment: Related to: [Python: fastest way to write pandas DataFrame to Excel on multiple sheets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25863381/python-fastest-way-to-write-pandas-dataframe-to-excel-on-multiple-sheets)

Comment: You must store and run all 50 CSVs in a single operation? Can't you load, transform, and then export *per file* to reduce the memory footprint of your script? This question isn't really a matter of speed, but more an issue with memory usage I gather.

Answer (score 2):

To fix your memory error, you have to increment your `cont` variable;

```
with pd.ExcelWriter('output.xlsx') as writer:
        cont = 0
        for x in List:
            x.to_excel(writer,sheet_name="csv_"+str(cont),index=False, engine='xlsxwriter',na_rep="NAN",startrow=1,startcol=1)
            cont += 1
```

A better syntax for this;

```
with pd.ExcelWriter('output.xlsx') as writer:
        for i, x in enumerate(List):
            x.to_excel(writer,sheet_name="csv_"+str(i),index=False, engine='xlsxwriter',na_rep="NAN",startrow=1,startcol=1)
```

And check if the file you want to output follows the [Excel Specifications.](https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/excel-specifications-and-limits-1672b34d-7043-467e-8e27-269d656771c3)

If all checks out and it is still too slow, you can use a [faster excel module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25863381/python-fastest-way-to-write-pandas-dataframe-to-excel-on-multiple-sheets).

Comment: Thanks, but that is not my question